# Maximum screen brightness not enough on Lenovo K49

Tags: brightness, lenovo

Though I adjust my screen brightness to maximum but it's still not enough. I have to type in the following every time when I wanna change which is troublesome.

sudo su -c "echo 4000 >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"

Can anybody talk about how you deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add `acpi_backlight=vendor` as a bootparameter in GRUB.
Ubuntu will use the backlightproperties of your notebookvendor.
When I use it, I can change the Light much more smooth. Maybe you can make it brighter then, aswell

Read here for information about how to add a bootparameter to grub. I think this is a pretty good tutorial.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

First you should try it temporarily. If it works as expected, you can add it permanently.

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbie in Linux. Could you please explain the steps in detail? Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer for you. Hope this tutorial helps